# Fonts while viewing stackoverflow appear too small in google chrome

Tags: support, user-interface, fonts, font-size

The font on other stack exchange sites including this one looks okay to me but on my ACER netbook (that comes with Windows 7 starter kit) and particularly in chrome browser the fonts are appearing really small . Why would this happen and how can I fix this ? As I already told the other stackexchange websites are working okay in chrome. I only see the problem while viewing stackoverflow website.

Comment: You may have changed the font size by mistake when browsing Stack Overflow. You should be able to reset it (`Ctrl + 0` normally does the trick).

Comment: @Oded yes CTRL+0 fixed it for me. Please put a short answer so that I can accept it. Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have changed the font size by mistake when browsing Stack Overflow.

You should be able to reset it (`Ctrl + 0` normally does the trick).

Answer (score 2):

An accidental zoom out by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scrollwheel is a more reasonable cause for this problem. Chrome remembers the zoom level on a per-domain basis (I've *.google.com always 1 step zoomed out as the default font size is fairly large on there).

You can indeed reset the zoom by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.